# Laravel 5.4 Maatwebsite Excel set column format to number

Tags: laravel-5.4, phpexcel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm trying to set the column/cell type to number. I'm getting "Number stored as text". I tried several combinations but none have any effect.

```
return Excel::create('Orders', function ($excel) use ($data) {
    $excel->setTitle('Open orders');
    $excel->setKeywords('orders, excel, export');

$excel->sheet('Open orders', function ($sheet) use ($data) {
 // $sheet->getStyle('C2:C10')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0.00'); // no effect
//    $sheet->setColumnFormat(array('C2:C10' => '0')); // no effect
$sheet->setColumnFormat(array('C2:C10' => '#0')); // no effect
// $sheet->getStyle('C2:C10')->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('$#,###'); // no effect

            $sheet->fromArray($data);
            $sheet->freezeFirstRow();
            $sheet->row(1, function ($row) {
            $row->setBackground('#aaffaa');
            $row->setBorder('solid', 'none', 'none', 'solid');
            });
        });
    })->download($type);
}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: i have the same question did you get any answer?

Comment: any answer for this? I want my cell to format text to columns

Comment: Hi, I solved this by moving one array to another and in the process I casted the values to float:  $arrayFinal[$i] = (float)$arrayOrg[$i]. No other method worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check what are you passing in the `$type` variable. if you are passing `CSV` it wouldn't formate the cell but if you are passing `XLS`, it will format it.

Comment: what do you mean $type? if I pass date its auto tab